# MultipartEntity: how can I adapt the parameter for uploading to RoR

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, parameters, multipartentity

Android studio

Hello People,

I want to change the parameters posted from my android app so that ruby on rails can accept the right form. Actually my Android app sends this form:

```
Parameters: {"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x53c1b10 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Clemens/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160911-9268-qqwltt.jpg>, @original_
filename="IMG_20160911_122254.jpg", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document\"; filename=\"IMG_20160911_122254.jpg\"\r\nCo
ntent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}
```

But I just want a small change, put "user" before like this {"user" => {"pictures" =>

```
 Parameters: { user{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x9599268 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Clemens/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160911-22652-1gxvlth.jpg>, @original_filename="Koala.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[file]\"; filename=\"Koala.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Document"}
```

Has anyone an idea? I would really thank you! Here is my code:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

      //  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

           entity.addPart("picture", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
              /////////  entity.addPart("website",
              ///////         new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
              ////////  entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);


                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200 ) {
                    // Server response
                   // responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                    responseString = "Foto erfolgreich hochgeladen";

                } else {
                    responseString = "Error: Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }
```

Comment: `Actually it sends this form:` ? Who is sending that?

Comment: `// Extra parameters if you want to pass to server`. Well there you go. Whats the problem?

Comment: Not so easy. When I use entity.addPart I need a FormBodyPart or a String and a ContentBody. So entity.addPart("user") doesnt work and entity.addPart("user", entity.addPart("picture", new FileBody(sourceFile)) doesn't work neighter

Comment: Of course not. You should -as you said yourself- add a String for instance. And you did not react on my first comment.

Comment: sorry I missunderstood your question. httppost.setEntity(entity) sends the file. And how or where do you think can I add a String? I need it in this form: {"user" =>{"picture" =>#<.....................}}

Comment: This is difficult talking as you still did not react on my first comment.

Comment: sorry, I dont know what your first commend is pointing to? My android app sends a parameter to my ruby on rails server. I showed the method, which is responsible for building and sending the parameter. Finally httppost.setEntity(entity) sends the parameter

Comment: `sorry, I dont know what your first commend is pointing to?` Well it was a quote so i wonder why you cannot find it back. Please reread your post.

Comment: I answered your question in my answer before. What do you want to hear from me?

Comment: "Actually it sends this form: ? Who is sending that?" Answer: my Android app, or more specific:  httppost.setEntity(entity)

Comment: It would be nice if you saw that `Actually my Android app sends this form:` is not true. What you send is only visible after `Here is my code`.

Comment: Ok sorry for my bad english, I see it the same way as you. So do you understand my problem and do you have a concret solution to this? I dont get it how you want to add a String or using the method "addPart"

Comment: `I see it the same way as you`??? You still not clarified the lines following `Actually it sends this form:`.

Comment: Hm? I wrote in my post after "Actually it send this form" the parameter: Parameters: {"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x53c1b10 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Clemens/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160911-9268-qqwltt.jpg>, @original_
filename="IMG_20160911_122254.jpg", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document\"; filename=\"IMG_20160911_122254.jpg\"\r\nCo
ntent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}    Don't you see this?

Comment: Yes of course i saw that. That's why i said that that is NOT sent by Android. You do not have to repeat all that stuff. Better explain what that really is as all that stufff is not sent by your Android app.

Comment: Ok the Android app sends a lot of encoded information. When this information is decoded by RoR server you get the parameter I posted. So do you now understand? And do you have a concret solution?I still dont know what you really want to hear, I think you understand my problem. I just didn't express clearly in my post

Comment: `I just didn't express clearly in my post ` If you are aware of that then why not take the time to edit it and write a decent story?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123141/discussion-between-peter-and-greenapps).